# sql, appending and determine value within a cell

Tags: sql

I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(colA DATE, colB INT, colC TEXT);

INSERT INTO table1(colA, colB, colC) VALUES ("2016-01-01", "1", "C1");
INSERT INTO table1(colA, colB, colC) VALUES ("2016-01-02", "2", "C2");

CREATE TABLE table2(colD TEXT, colE TEXT, colF TEXT);

INSERT INTO table2(colD, colE, colF) VALUES ("2016-01-03", "3", "F1");
INSERT INTO table2(colD, colE, colF) VALUES ("2016-01-04", "4", "F2");
```

What I am trying to do is append one table to the other and then add another column (colG). A different message should be displayed in each cell in colG depending on the date range in colA. I will also be adding another column that will have a message depending on the value of the integer. So I am looking for a general approach. Any ideas how to achieve that? Much appreciated. This is what I have tried:

```
 SELECT colA, 
       colB, 
       CASE When date <2016-01-01 "daterange A"
            When date <2016-01-01<2016-01-02 "daterangeB"
            When date <2016-01-02<2016-01-03 "daterangeC"
            When date <2016-01-03<2016-01-04 "daterangeD"

       AS colG 
FROM (
   SELECT colA, colB FROM table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT colD, colE FROM table2
) union_tbl;
```

Comment: where is  the column date .. from which table you  you obtain this value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your syntax were correct, your SQL should do what you want.  Something like this:

```
SELECT colA, 
       colB, 
       (CASE When date < '2016-01-01' then 'daterange A'
             When date < '2016-01-02' then 'daterangeB'
             When date < '2016-01-03' then 'daterangeC'
             When date < '2016-01-04' then 'daterangeD'
        END) AS colG 
FROM (SELECT colA, colB FROM table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT colD, colE FROM table2
     ) t;
```

Notes:

- Date constants need to be wrapped in single quotes (in most databases).
- String constants should be wrapped in single quotes (the ANSI standard).
- `case` statements evaluate each clause in order, so you can simplify the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the data types on your table?

- colA is a DATE and colD is a TEXT
- colB is an INT AND colE is a TEXT

In most database engines your union statement would fail if the above datatypes are correct. Most relational database engines require the datatypes to match across members of a union statement.

```
SELECT colA, 
       colB, 
       (CASE When date < '2016-01-01' then 'daterange A'
             When date < '2016-01-02' then 'daterangeB'
             When date < '2016-01-03' then 'daterangeC'
             When date < '2016-01-04' then 'daterangeD'
        END) AS colG 
FROM (SELECT 
             CAST(colA AS TEXT) AS colA
          ,  CAST(colB AS TEXT) AS colB
      FROM table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT colD, colE FROM table2
     ) tba;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should obtain also the column date  and convert your string date in date

```
  SELECT colA, 
         colB, 
         (CASE When `date` < str_to_date('2016-01-01', '%Y-%m%d') then 'daterange A'
               When `date` < str_to_date('2016-01-02', '%Y-%m%d') then 'daterangeB'
               When `date` < str_to_date('2016-01-03', '%Y-%m%d') then 'daterangeC'
               When `date` < str_to_date('2016-01-04', '%Y-%m%d') then 'daterangeD'
          END) AS colG 
  FROM (SELECT colA, colB, `date` FROM table1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT colD, colE, `date` FROM table2
       ) my_t;
```